# top 5 value via vector iterator using function

Tags: c++, vector

Hi all I'm having compilation error when I'm using vector iterator in a function itself.

i've tried executing the example from http://ideone.com/tTDYU5 and it works perfectly fine. However when I try to put it in a function things gets ugly why is this so?

```
vector <PointTwoD> topfive;
void MissionPlan::topfives()
{   
    topfive.assign( point1.begin(), point1.end() ); 
    sort(topfive.begin(), topfive.end(), sortByCiv);
}

void MissionPlan::DisplayTopFiveResult()
{
    missionplan.topfives();

    vector<PointTwoD>::iterator it = topfive.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 && it != topfive.end(); i++) {
    cout <<  "X axis: " << pointtwoD.xcord  << "          " << "Y axis: " << pointtwoD.ycord <<  "          " << "CIV Index: " << pointtwoD.civIndex << *it;
    ++it;
    }


}
```

Comment: @YuHao sorry, didn't know that cos I was advised to post this as a new question as it's on a different method.

Comment: What is getting ugly now ? You haven't posted the exact problem as per previous post ? What is `pointtwoD.xcord` and `pointtwoD.ycord` ?
It looks like it should print same cords, along with different `*it`

Comment: Copy/paste the exact compiler error you're getting.

Comment: @P0W the value are all in the class PointTwoD so i'm trying print the value of X and Y cord base on the top 5 CIV value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since *"the value are all in the class `PointTwoD` "*

Use `it` to print those :

```
vector<PointTwoD>::iterator it = topfive.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 && it != topfive.end(); i++) {
    cout <<  "X axis: "  << it->xcord  << " " 
         <<  "Y axis: "  << it->ycord  << " " 
         << "CIV Index: " << it->civIndex << std::endl;
    ++it;
    }
```

If still this throws compilation error, you need to provide more info.

Comment: sorry, I just pick up C++ 1 week back.. it works fine now. But I have another question, if I decide to make xcord, ycord and civindex as Private. Than it would definitely affect the function here right?

Comment: @koi_s3ng It depends, in this case, I dont think it would affect.

Comment: i wish I could accept the ans but I do not have enuf points to do it.

Comment: is there any recommended sites which I can get reference from in regards to C++?

Comment: @koi_s3ng Sure : This [site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) and [Good Books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1870232)